# Auto formatting flattens nested list

Tags: bug, markdown

I often use nested lists in my answers and came across the following problem:

When entering a nested list like

```
* A
  * B
```

pressing Shift+Enter causes the auto formatter to flatten the list to

```
 * A
 * B
 * List item
```

Note that this does not happen when simply pressing Enter, but it can be quite frustrating when you have built a more complex nested list hierarchy and accidentally press Shift during line breaks.

#### Possible solution

Instead of clamping all spaces in front of a bullet into a single one, compute the hierarchy level for every bullet and set spaces accordingly, while inserting new list item in the current hierarchy level.

**EDIT:** I'm using Firefox 54 (64 bit) on Ubuntu

Comment: I can't repro this on Chrome/Win10. If I press shift+enter in a list it inserts for me the text *enter code here* which is also confusing and doesn't happen when I'm on a *normal* line. My list doesn't get flattened in the test-cases I tried.

Comment: I'm using Firefox/Ubuntu. *enter code here* only gets inserted if my current line is already indented by at least 4 spaces.